# Integer pattern searching using effective index

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I effectively use the index on an INT/BIGINT column for pattern-matching queries.

Sample data

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempIDTable') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #TempIDTable;

CREATE TABLE #TempIDTable
(
    ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);

-- Pattern ending with 123
INSERT INTO #TempIDTable(ID) VALUES(1123);
INSERT INTO #TempIDTable(ID) VALUES(2123);
INSERT INTO #TempIDTable(ID) VALUES(3123);
-- Pattern ending with 223
INSERT INTO #TempIDTable(ID) VALUES(7223);
INSERT INTO #TempIDTable(ID) VALUES(8223);
INSERT INTO #TempIDTable(ID) VALUES(9223);
-- Pattern ending with 323
INSERT INTO #TempIDTable(ID) VALUES(52323);
INSERT INTO #TempIDTable(ID) VALUES(53323);
INSERT INTO #TempIDTable(ID) VALUES(5323);

-- Selecting all rows with pattern ending in 123
DECLARE @Pattern INT = 123;

SELECT 
    T.ID, Pattern = (T.ID % 1000)
FROM 
    #TempIDTable T
WHERE 
    (T.ID % 1000) = @Pattern;

SET @Pattern  = 223;

SELECT 
    T.ID, Pattern = (T.ID % 1000)
FROM 
    #TempIDTable T
WHERE 
    (T.ID % 1000) = @Pattern;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempIDTable') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #TempIDTable;
GO
```

Basically, given a pattern (an `INT` input), I have to find the rows matching ID column. How do I create an INDEX to be used effectively by the query? Is there any other way of rewriting the query to effectively use the index?

Currently, the Execution Plan shows a scan:

[image]

If it helps, this is on SQL Server 2017 on Windows

Comment: Add `Pattern` to your base table (or a view) as a computed column and index that.

Comment: Is `@pattern` a parameter which varies with each execution of this code?

Comment: Binary numbers aren't text, they have no patterns. Even with text, a suffix search wouldn't benefit from any index. What you try to search is the base-10 division remainder, not any kind of pattern.

Comment: For a prefix pattern such as `'123%` you can do a start and end range `WHERE T.ID >= 12300 AND T.ID < 12400` that will get a seek

Comment: @JeroenMostert , yes that is what i have now. Just wanted to check if there is a mathematical way of doing this which could induce a seek instead of scan

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , thank you, yes i am fully aware that this is an INT operation and not a string operation. Just for the sake of ease of understanding i called this as a "pattern matching"

Comment: @Charlieface , this wouldnt work all the time right, because the numbers keep increasing. I know the list of "patterns", but not the IDs that are generated.

Comment: It sounds like you are storing multiple things in one column, and perhaps you should be splitting it out into two or three columns. And as I and @PanagiotisKanavos said, a prefix search would work, not a suffix search. There is no way you can induce a seek on the right (more detailed) part of an index key while ignoring the left (less detailed) part of the key. You could maybe do multiple searches in order to match each possible prefix, but that might be slow

Comment: @PrasGov if you understand that's not a string there's no point talking about patterns. If you need to treat the number as a string, if some part of it is significant, then you *shouldn't* be using a single field but several. What are you *actually* trying to do? What does that field contain? Are you trying to create an "intelligent" key? Such fields should only be used for display, not primary keys or querying. There are several articles that discuss this problem and how to solve it, eg [Intelligent Keys aren't that dumb](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/intelligent-keys-arent-that-dumb/)

Comment: If you store the individual fields, it's actually very easy to generate the smart key with a persisted computed column *and* index it. If you think you can use a single long number to "pack" multiple fields, there are other **far** better options, like table compression or using a columnstore index

Comment: @Charlieface , yes, for some tables , i have it stored in seperate columns. I was just curious if there would be a "mathematical" way to achieve seek

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , Yes it is an intelligent key. For queries that do single ID matching s, the column has the "intelligent key" as a single column. I acheive seek here. 
For range queries, like select a range of rows belonging to a pattern , i get a scan if i do a single column search. This was what i was trying to avoid. I have the "intelligent parts" stored in seperate columns wherever i will have a range search or choosing a bulk of rows

Comment: @SMor , it wont vary per execution, but across multiple servers, the pattern will be different. All queries in database 1 will use pattern 1 (123 for example), database 2 will use pattern 2 (223) etc. (These are not real pattern, but rather an simplified version of what is on the system)

Comment: Don't use the intelligent key for searches then. Why not filter on the individual fields? What is the *actual* table schema and *actual* queries you want to perform? Why not write `WHERE CategoryId=1 and SubcategoryId between 3 and 5` instead of `WHERE ID/100000= 1 AND ID%100 between 3 and 5`? Indexing individual fields is easy. To index "parts", you'll have to actually convert them back to individual fields through computed columns, in any database. Even in databases that allow indexing expressions, they actually execute the expression and persist the result in the index